# Java from currentTimeMillis to seconds giving either 0 or 1

Tags: java

I am trying to run sorting on around 5 million elements and need to record the time it takes.
I am doing the following :

```
long startTime = (System.currentTimeMillis());
My Sorting Algorithm {}
long totalTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

In milliseconds i get the appropriate time but when i try to convert it into seconds like this:

```
long totalTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
```

it gives me either 0 or 1 which is incorrect.

I also tried making it double and got 0.0
    double totalTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);

Infact,TimeUnit is also giving 0
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalTime) .

Can someone please help me pointing out what goings wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using integer division and assigning the result to an integer type. The end result is therefore always integer.

To fix, use:

```
double totalTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000.0);
```

Comment: Aah! thanks a ton to all.. I always make that mistake

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing what integer division looks like. You are converting to double **after** the integer division so that does not make any difference. Divide by 1000.0 and possibly convert the numerator to double before performing the division:

```
double d = ((double) (System.currentTimeMillis()-start))/1000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide by 1000.0.

If you want to do microbenchmarks, don't roll your own, use JMH: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/